# Possible error at definition of essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and $a\in\Omega$, with $f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega\backslash\{  a\})$.

A singularity at $a$ is called essential, iff $\forall\, w\in\mathbb{C},\ \exists$ a sequence $(z_n)_{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=a$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=w$.

I know that there are quite a few different defintions of an essential singularity, but they all amount to the fact, that with the possible exception of a point, every complex value is adopted in an arbitrary small neighborhood around the singularity. (Great Picard theorem) At least, if I am correct.

Now how does this first definition in my post make sense? This just seems completely wrong to me. I might live with something like

"A singularity is called essential, iff $\forall\, w\in\mathbb{C},\ \exists$ a sequence $(z_n)_{n}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=c,\, \ c\in\mathbb{C}$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=w$."

But if $a$ is fixed and the singularity, how can this be true?

Comment: Replace "A singularity" with "The singularity at $a$".

Comment: First: never saw such a **definition** of essential singularity. This is the result of the impressive Picard's theorem...and it also mentions that there can be one exception , so in *your* definition it should, imo, be written that $\;\forall 2\in\Bbb C\;$ "with at most one exception" .... etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio The definition doesn't say each $w$ is attained, only that it's the limit of a sequence of images (whose source sequence converges to the singularity). It's far weaker than Picard, it's essentially Casorati-Weierstraß.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed so. Thanks,

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, exactly. What bothers me is the fact that for all $w\in\mathbb{C}$, $\lim f(z_n)=w$ should hold for the same sequence $(z_n)_n$ with $a$ as limit.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta No, the order of quantifiers matters. We have $\bigl(\forall w\bigr)\bigl(\exists (z_n)\bigr)$, the sequence is allowed to depend on $w$. If we had $\bigl(\exists (z_n)\bigr)\bigl(\forall w\bigr)$, that would evidently be wrong.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed, but this is not what I meant. We can choose $(z_n)_n$ but not its limit, which is supposed to be $a$ for every sequence.

Comment: Yes, $a$ is the singularity in question. If we have a sequence staying away from $a$, that wouldn't tell us anything about the behaviour of $f$ near $a$.

Comment: This is simply not the definition. The definition is "isolated singularity which is not a pole and not removable".

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand, you are correct. However, still this is somehow different from being dense. Is it just another formulation of the CW theorem?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It is the definition in my script. My script (from a beginners course in complex analysis) distinguishes 3 cases of singularites, the last being this definition of an essential singularity.

Comment: Yes, it's another formulation of Casorati-Weierstraß. By C-W, for every (large enough, so that we stay inside $\Omega$) $n$ the image of the punctured disk $U_n = \{ z : 0 < \lvert z-a\rvert < 1/n\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, so we can find a $z_n \in U_n$ with $\lvert w - f(z_n)\rvert < 1/n$. Then by construction $z_n \to a$ and $f(z_n) \to w$. Conversely, if there is an $m$ such that $f(U_m)$ is not dense, take any $w$ in the interior of $\mathbb{C}\setminus f(U_m)$, and you can't find a sequence $(z_n)$ with $z_n \to a$ and $f(z_n) \to w$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It's a non-standard, and in my view not good, definition, but as long as we don't call non-isolated singularities essential, it's equivalent to the standard definition.

Comment: @DanielFischer This is exactly what I was looking for. Mind you, writing an answer, so I can accept and close?

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course it's equivalent to the standard definition. But it's a very bad idea - going to cause confusion. For example, with this definition the correct statement of Casorti-W would be "An isolated singularity must be either removable, a pole or an essential singularity".

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "my script". If you're referring to your notes, you should look again at the book, very carefully. If it actually gives that as the _definition_ then it seems to me you need a different book - the stuff in that book is going to cause a lot of confusion. Another possibiilty is that the definition in the book  is the standard one, and in your notes you're confusing the _definition_ with a certain _theorem_.

Comment: Btw I don't find "a beginners course in complex analysis" on amazon. Is that a book or what?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The "script" is probably written by the lecturer.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No, a script as mentioned. A university script to be exact. As I said, 3 different possibilities for singularities are presented. Usually the essential one is defined as neither a pole nor a removable, but in my script it directly states the CW theorem for the essential one. But yes, I was confused as you predicted. I will talk to my professor about this issue. There are quite a lot things not being pedagogically fruitful in this script.

Comment: Is this script online somewhere?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich not accessible to everyone. I can only send you the pdf or a single page, but no link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual definition says that an isolated singularity that is neither removable nor a pole is called an essential singularity. (And some authors also call non-isolated singularities, e.g. branch points, essential singularities.)

Then the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem says that the isolated singularity $a$ of $f\in \mathcal{H}(\Omega\setminus \{a\})$ is essential if and only if $f(U\setminus \{a\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ for every neighbourhood $U \subset \Omega$ of $a$. [It may be stated with only the direction "$a$ essential $\implies f(U\setminus \{a\})$ dense for all $U$", but since the only possibilities for an isolated singularity are to be removable, a pole, or essential, and neither removable singularities nor poles have this property, the other direction follows.]

The definition you were given is an alternative formulation of the characterisation of essential (isolated) singularities by the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem. For, if we choose a sequence $\{U_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of neighbourhoods of $a$ in $\Omega$ with $\lvert z - a\rvert < 1/n$ for all $z \in U_n$, given an arbitrary $w\in \mathbb{C}$, by the Casorati-Weierstraß theorem there is a $z_n \in U_n\setminus \{a\}$ with $\lvert f(z_n) - w\rvert < 1/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $z_n \in U_n$ implies $\lvert z_n - a\rvert < 1/n$, we have $z_n \to a$, and by construction we also have $f(z_n) \to w$. Conversely, if for every $w \in \mathbb{C}$ there is a sequence $(z_n)$ in $\Omega \setminus \{a\}$ with $z_n \to a$ and $f(z_n) \to w$, then $f(U\setminus \{a\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $a$. For, given such a neighbourhood, we have $z_n \in U$ for all large enough $n$ by the definition of $z_n \to a$, and consequently $w \in \overline{f(U\setminus \{a\})}$. Since $w$ was arbitrary, that means $f(U\setminus \{a\})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

If that's actually the definition in the "script" you're using then in my opinion you have a bad script - giving totally non-standard defintions is a bad idea, going to cause confusion when comparing with other references.

The standard story is this:

Defintions: $f$ has an isolated singularity at $a$ if ... . An isolated singularity at $a$ is *removable* if ...., it is a *pole* if $\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$, and otherwise it is an *essential singularity*.

Theorem (Riemann) If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $a$and $f$ is bounded near $a$ then the singularity is removable.

THeorem (C-W). If $f$ has an essential singularity at $a$ then $f(D'(a,r))$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ for every $r>0$.

(Here $D'(a,r)=\{z:0<|z-a|<r\}$. Of course the conclusion says that for every $w$ there exist $z_n\to a$ with $f(z_n)\to w$.)

Proof: If $f(D'(a,r))$ is not dense there exist $w\in\mathbb C$ and $\rho>0$ such that $f(D'(a,r)))\cap D(w,\rho)=\emptyset$. This says that $$|f(z)-w|\ge\rho\quad(z\in D'(a,r)).$$

So $g=1/(f-w)$ is bounded near $a$, so it has a removable singularity.
And $f=w+1/g$, so $f$ has either a removable singularity or a pole, depending on whether or not $g(a)=0$. QED.

Answer (score -1):

If $f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega\backslash\{  a\})$, then $a$ is called a isolated sinfgularity of $f$.

The singularity is $a$ is called essential, if $a$ is not a pole and $a$ is not a removable singularity of $f$.

THEOREM(Casorati- Weierstraß): The singularity $a$ is essential iff $\forall\, w\in\mathbb{C},\ \exists$ a sequence $(z_n)$ in $ \Omega \setminus \{a\}$ with $z_n \to a$ and $f(z_n) \to w$.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the usual, and possibly neither the correct, wording of the CW theorem. It could be one point left out and again, that $\;\forall\;$ could be wrong. More usually I've seen the theorem using the wording "dense" for $\;f\left(\Omega\setminus\{a\}\right)\;$ in $\;\Bbb C\;$

Comment: This is the point. The CW theorem is stated using the property of density, but I am unable to understand why a dense image would be equivalent to what you just wrote. You only have one limit of the sequence, how can u obtain every value $f(w)$ with only one sequence? I would argue this to be impossible.

Comment: Why don't you add the proof (which is very easy) ? If $\inf_z |f(z)-w| > \epsilon$ then $\frac{(z-w)^2}{f(z)-w}$ is bounded and holomorphic, thus analytic, thus so is $f(z)$